# Using "window Translucent Status = true" and want to display Text View value just after action bar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme, android-styles, android-statusbar

I want to display my text just after the "Action Bar". Because I am using window translucent status therefore my text is appearing on "Status Bar".

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
</style>
```

I tried the textview property layout:margin top = 100dp and this is working fine for me.. but i think this solution may not work on other mobile phones.

Would someone knew any better way to do it in proper way?

Comment: Please post the layout XML.

Comment: @Lamorak Following is the XML code: 

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".LoginActivity"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:id="@+id/login_screen"
    android:transitionGroup="false"> </RelativeLayout>

Comment: Please add the code to the question with propper formatting. Also I believe this code is not complete.

Comment: @Lamorak I am unable to format code in my reply... yes i have some text fields and button within that XML file.. should i post the complete sample code?